# How to compare two fields and then set boolean in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

This is my current query:

```
SELECT i.itemNo, Nz(TotalOrdered,0) AS Sumofqtyordered, Nz(TotalReturned,0) AS sumofqtyreturn, Nz(TotalIssued,0) AS sumofqtyissued, (Nz(TotalOrdered,0)-Nz(TotalIssued,0)-Nz(TotalReturned,0)) AS Balance
FROM ((item AS i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyordered) AS TotalOrdered FROM delivered_item GROUP BY itemno)  AS d ON d.itemno=i.itemno) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyreturn) AS TotalReturned FROM item_return GROUP BY itemno)  AS r ON r.itemno=i.itemno) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyissued) AS TotalIssued FROM item_issued GROUP BY itemno)  AS iss ON iss.itemno=i.itemno;
```

How to compare the field(minqty) in my item table with the balance in the query? And i will add one more field ,PlaceOrder(Boolean) in this query. It is set to yes when balance is less than minqty and no when it is above or equal to minqty? any 1 can help with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `SELECT`:

```
((Nz(TotalOrdered,0)-Nz(TotalIssued,0)-Nz(TotalReturned,0))<[minqty]) AS PlaceOrder
```

It will return -1 (True) or 0 (False).  If you want it to actually return 'Yes' or 'No':

```
IIf((Nz(TotalOrdered,0)-Nz(TotalIssued,0)-Nz(TotalReturned,0))<[minqty],'Yes','No') AS PlaceOrder
```

Comment: thx alot...but can i replace the Nz(totalordered,0)...... with balance?is there any possible impacts?

Comment: You should be able to do that without issue

Comment: hi,hope you still remember this. May i ask you if i want to produce an error message when the (sum of qtyreturned+sum of qtyissued ) is over sum of qtyordered, can this be done in access by writing code or any other methods?thanks alot

Comment: @parakmiakos May i ask you if i want to produce an error message when the (sum of qtyreturned+sum of qtyissued ) is over sum of qtyordered, can this be done in access by writing code or any other methods?

Comment: What do you mean by error message?  Like a pop up or message box?  What's the goal of doing so?

Comment: because if he (sum of qtyreturned+sum of qtyissued ) is over sum of qtyordered, error msg shd be produced telling the user to check

Comment: Add in a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE (sum of qtyreturned + sum of qtyissued) > qtyordered`.  Then the user will know anything returned by the query needs to be checked.